# Concatenate a char into a string

Tags: c++, concatenation, string-concatenation

I got a `_n` function returning an int with a `q` string param.
Since I'm italian string in param may contain accented letters (such as àèìòù).
Those special letters are not rendered correctly in cout and I was trying to use chars, but the concatenation with the + operator is not working.

```cpp
U = _n("Quanto " + char (232) + " urgente l'evento?");
```

```
[Error] invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char [19]' to binary 'operator+'
```

I also tried different ways such as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItMXl.png)

Comment: Well not really

Comment: why not? The same answer could apply here. If not you should explain why

Comment: Relevant to [the underlying issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), but not to the question that was asked: [How to inject non-ASCII characters into a string literal in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966122/how-to-inject-non-ascii-characters-into-a-string-literal-in-c-c)

Comment: Actually the concatenation works but the char is rendered as 'broken' @largest_prime_is_463035818

Comment: You asked about the error reported by the compiler. Once your code compiles, fixing the functionality is a separate question. However, before posting a new question about it, see [C++ Extended ASCII Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43390280/c-extended-ascii-code).

Comment: This is an XY problem. Concatenation isn't the problem. The problem is the string encoding and encoding of the COUT.

Comment: please include a [mcve] of your code in the question. I believe the duplicate is not appropriate for your actual issue but we need more information